# Backbone.js: View does not reflect Model change in Todo App

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I've been following Addy Osmani's book *Developing Backbone.js Applications*, [the version available online for free.](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#application-view) As such, the first exercise is the much touted sample "Todo app", which can also be lifted from Backbone's original documentation samples.

While the app updates the view when a new entry is added to the list of things to do, I've hit an odd snafu: When I edit a list entry and press the enter button, nothing happens. The input doesn't go out of focus and the label in the entry doesn't update automatically. However, the Model does save the edited entry, because when I refresh the page, the edited entry features the change I made it to it.

I have no idea what is going on, as the view does listen to model changes.

Here's the code:

```
app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "li",
template: _.template($("#item-template").html()),
events:{
    "dblclick label":"edit",
    "keypress .edit": "updateOnEnter",
    "blur .edit": "close"
},
initalize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
},
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.myInput = this.$(".edit");
    return this;
},
edit: function(){
    this.$el.addClass("editing");
    this.myInput.focus();
},
close: function(){
    var value = this.myInput.val().trim();
    if(value) this.model.save({ title: value});
    this.$el.removeClass("editing");
},
updateOnEnter: function(x){
    if(x.keyCode === 13)
        this.close();
}});

app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#app"),
statsTemplate: _.template($("#stat-template").html()),
events:{
    "keypress #newentry": "createOnEnter",
    "click #clear-completed": "clearCompleted",
    "click #toggle-all": "toggleAllComplete"
},
initialize: function(){
    this.allCheck = this.$("#toggle-all")[0];
    this.newJob = this.$("#newentry");
    this.main = this.$("#main");
    this.foot = this.$("#foot");
    this.listenTo(app.TodoCol, "add", this.addOne);
    this.listenTo(app.TodoCol, "reset", this.addAll);
    this.listenTo(app.TodoCol, "change:completed", this.filterOne);
    this.listenTo(app.TodoCol, "filter", this.filterAll);
    this.listenTo(app.TodoCol, "all", this.render);
    app.TodoCol.fetch();
    console.log(app.TodoCol.toJSON());
},
addOne: function(todo){
    var view = new app.TodoView({model: todo});
    $("#items").append(view.render().el);
},
addAll: function(todo){
    this.$("items").html("");
    app.TodoCol.each(this.addOne, this);
},
filterOne: function(todo){
    todo.trigger("visible");
},
filterAll: function(){
    app.TodoCol.each(this.filterOne, this);
},
render: function(){
    var comp = app.TodoCol.getCompleted().length;
    var open = app.TodoCol.getOpen().length;
    if(app.TodoCol.length){
        this.main.show();
        this.foot.show();
        this.foot.html(this.statsTemplate({
            completed: comp,
            remain: open
        }));
        this.$("#filters li").removeClass("active")
            .filter('[href="#/' + ( app.TodoFilter || '' ) + '"]')
            .addClass('selected');
    }else{
        this.main.hide();
        this.foot.hide();
    }
    this.allCheck.checked = !open;
},
newEntry: function() {
  return {
    title: this.newJob.val().trim(),
    order: app.TodoCol.nextOrder(),
    completed: false
  };
},
createOnEnter: function(event){
    if(event.which !== 13 || !this.newJob.val().trim())
        return;
    app.TodoCol.create(this.newEntry());
    this.newJob.val("");
},
clearCompleted: function(){
    _.invoke(app.TodoCol.getCompleted(), "destroy");
    return false;
},
toggleAllComplete: function(){
    var comp = this.allCheck.checked;
    app.TodoCol.each(function(t){
        t.save({ completed: comp});
    });
}});
```

Here are the models for good measure:

```
app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults:{
    title: "",
    completed: false
},
toggle: function(){
    this.save({completed: !this.get("completed")});
}});

app.List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: app.Todo,
localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todo-backbone"),
getCompleted: function(){
    return this.where({completed: true});
},
getOpen: function(){
    return this.where({completed: false});
},
nextOrder: function(){
    if(!this.length) return 1;
    return this.last().get("order") + 1;
},
comparator: function(todo){
    return todo.get("order");
}});
```

Please help me!

Comment: What happens when you `app.TodoCol.fetch()`? Does your server send anything back? Does your `createOnEnter` ever get called? Those are the only two things I see that would add anything to your collection.

Comment: Never mind, I did the app from scratch. It works now. I believe it had something to do with the rendering function, but I really don't know.